# Show that $x_0=1$ is a Detractor Point when $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f(x)=x^3$. The fixed points are $\lbrace0,1,-1\rbrace$. I have shown that $0$ is an attractor point, becaues it is Lyapunov stable and is contained in $(-1,1)$. First, I supposed that $x\in(0,1)$, consequently for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$
0<f^n(x)<\cdots<f^2(x)<f(x)<x<1
$$
Because $\lbrace f^n(x)\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded below and decreasing, it converges to its infimum which is $0$ and therefore $(0,1)$ is a subset of the stable set of $0$. By repeating the procedure, so is $(-1,0)$. Then I showed that it is Lyapunov stable. It would suffice to assume for given $0<\varepsilon$, that $\delta=\min\lbrace1,\varepsilon\rbrace$. Hence, $0$ is an attractor point.
Now, I am trying to show that $1$ is not an attractor point and I cannot proceed further because I cannot obviate the following for $x\in(1,\infty)$:
$$
1<x<f(x)<f^2(x)<\cdots<f^n(x)
$$
Clearly $\lbrace f^n(x)\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded above. How am I supposed to show that $|f^n(x)-f^n(1)|<\varepsilon$ for any given $0<\varepsilon$ provided that for each $x$, $|x-1|<\delta$ for some positive $\delta$?

Comment: Why do you want to show that an unstable point is stable? If $x=1+a$, $a>0$ then $x^2>1+2a$ and thus $x^3>x+2a$. Or in total $f(x)-1>3(x-1)$.

Comment: I do not wish to prove that an unstable point is stable. I merely wish to show that $\mathcal{W}^u(1)=(0,\infty)\setminus\lbrace1\rbrace$.

Comment: Exploring $W^u(1)$ means you want examine the sequences $f^{-n}(x)=x^{1/3^{n}}$.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see.